# Can anyone pls tell me why my output is None None?

Tags: python

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 :
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
    handle = open(name)
di=dict()
lst=list()
for line in handle:
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) < 3 or line.startswith != 'From':
        continue
    lst.append(words[1])
    for word in lst:
        di[word] = di.get(word,0)+1
largest = None
theword = None
for k,v in di.items():
    if largest is None or largest < v:
        largest = v
        theword = k
print(theword,largest)
```

*the question is

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.*

Comment: `line.startswith != 'From'` is always true, so `continue` always happens and the dictionary will be empty. `line.startswith` is a method so it can never equal a string.

Comment: @kaya3 however my code is still mismatch with the desired output :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you say "my code mismatches the desired output" we have no idea what your code is outputting or what your desired output should be. Could you help us? Or perhaps open another question with your specific problem?

Comment: @rajah9 yeah thats my bad, sr about it. Btw I've already found my answer for my problem. Thank u for caring